# How does the Python re.sub() function work?

Tags: python, join, module, replace

Would someone please explain the following code execution?
I am a novice in Python; I got stuck between 're' and 'sub'.

```
import re

a = 'a..!b...c???d;;'
chars = [',', '!', '.', ';', '?']

print re.sub('[%s]' % ''.join(chars), '', a)
```

Comment: What didn't you understand in the code?

Comment: What *part* don't you understand? Did you read the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) documentation at all?

Comment: You can always use help(re.sub).  It will give you a basic rundown of what re.sub is and how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

The code applies a round-about way to remove punctuation. It can be simplified to:

```
re.sub('[,!.;?]', '', a)
```

where `[....]` is a regular expression character class definition. It'll match any character in the input text that is a member of that class, so any comma, exclamation mark, etc. will match.

The `.sub()` function will replace any match with the second argument, in this case the empty string, removing all named punctuation marks.

This function is better filled by the [`str.translate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), whose second argument is a sequence of characters to delete from the input text.

```
a.translate(None, ',!.;?')
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = 'a..!b...c???d;;'
>>> a.translate(None, ',!.;?')
'abcd'
```